# How to render html by div tag in android

Tags: android

I have HTML and I can use Webview to render the HTML and display it in the app. But it is not as straight forward.

I have sections in the HTML separated by div tags.

So how do you render it in the app?

[image]
[image]

I don't want to use Webview, Cardview would be great!

Comment: List down your **DIV**, pass it to a **RecyclerView**. Use CardView for each DIV in Holder and use `Html.fromHtml(div)` to load DIV.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, Use the standard **RecyclerView** and create an adapter which extends **RecyclerView.Adapter**. Each item in your list should then be implemented using the CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This will result into a layout similar to the image below. If you are not sure what a RecyclerView is or how to use it, please read more about it and the various android design widgets here https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-design-library
[image: Android CardView]